# Ionic Firebase Angular Async validation

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I'm trying to set up validation so if the username is taken a new user cant signup with the same username. I'm getting an error cant find afDatabase this is occurring in the *username.ts*. It cant find the FirebaseDatabase that is defined in the constructor. Why is this happening? Thanks for the help.

> Cannot read property 'afDatabase' of undefined

**username.ts**

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

export class UsernameValidator {

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase) {

  }
  static checkUsername(control: FormControl): any {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if(this.afDatabase.orderByChild('username').equals(control.value)){
          resolve({
            "username taken": true
          });
        }else{
          resolve(null);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

**profile-setup.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

import { Profile } from './../../models/profile';
import { UsernameValidator } from  '../../validators/username';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile-setup',
  templateUrl: 'profile-setup.html',
})
export class ProfileSetupPage {
  profile = {} as Profile;

  profileForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase, public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams, public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public toastCtrl: ToastController) {

      this.profileForm = formBuilder.group({
        username: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required]), UsernameValidator.checkUsername]
      });
  }

  createProfile(){
    if(this.profileForm.valid){
      this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {
        this.afDatabase.object(`profile/${auth.uid}`).set(this.profile)
          .then(() => this.navCtrl.setRoot('TabsPage'))
      })
    }else if (!this.profileForm.controls.username.valid){
      let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: 'Invalid Username',
        duration: 3000,
        position: 'bottom'
      });
      toast.present();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `UsernameValidator` class you have defined the `checkUsername` method as `static`, meaning it can't be tied to a specific instance of the class. However, you are using `this.afDatabase` inside of this method, which has to come from a specific instance of the class.

And so, your implementation of `checkUsername` is contradicting with the fact that you've defined it as `static`. Try resolving this contradiction and see if that fixes the issue.